# Does push mail service utilise constant internet connection?

Tags: email

I searched Google for this but only found that push mail requires constant internet connection.

---

I want to know whether Push mail really USES constant internet connection? If so then what is the difference between push mail service and "constantly refreshing inbox"?

Ps: please don't suggest me to upgrade my plan, I want to know the difference.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push mail shouldn't use the internet connection while idle, but it has to keep a connection open to the server. That's why push mail needs the internet connection.

The difference between push mail and polling is that when using push mail, the client opens a persistent connection to the server. After this the connection is idle. When a new message is received by the mail server, it notifies the client of the new message, and the client decides whether to download it or not. When using "pull" (polling) mail, the client has to periodically open a connection to the mail server and check for new messages.

The only reason your internet connection would be used while idle is if the connection to the server is broken and needs to be reconnected.

See [Push email - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_email) for more detailed info.